# How to solve Vue-Cli Javascript disabled error

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I want to build vue-cli 3 to my computer. I've created my first folder with vue-cli control panel than I faced with a blank page. In my index.html, I've discovered  `<strong>We're sorry but vue-test doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>` error. How to fix that and create a working properly folder instead?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>vue-test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but vue-test doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```